# How to stop the Spring Source TC server on my Windows 7 system

Tags: windows-7, tomcat

Today on Windows 7 system when I hit localhost:8080 in my browser I saw SpringSource tc Server running, quite unexpectedly.
Here is the message that I found.

> As you may have guessed by now, this is the default SpringSource tc Server home page. It can be found on the local filesystem at:

```
  $TC_SERVER_HOME/webapps/ROOT/index.html
```

> where "$TC_SERVER_HOME" is the root of the tc Server installation directory for Tomcat. If you're seeing this page, and you don't think you should be, then you're either a user who has arrived at a new installation of tc Server, or you're an administrator who hasn't got his/her setup quite right. Providing the latter is the case, please refer to the tc Server Documentation for detailed setup and administration information.

I have tried doing echo $TC_SERVER_HOME/webapps/ROOT/
to know the install folder. So that I could stop the batch script at that location.

Its just printing $TC_SERVER_HOME/webapps/ROOT/

This server is almost similar to Tomcat.Problem is how to stop it? How to find its Install Directory and shut that down? I presume there would be some batch file and I would have to shut that down?

I am on Windows 7 system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How do I to stop the Spring Source TC server?

As the message you have quoted in your questions states **"please refer to the tc Server Documentation for detailed setup and administration information."**

If you have already installed the tc Runtime instance as a Windows Service, use the Windows Services control panel to start and stop it.

---

#### Windows: Starting and Stopping tc Runtime Instances as Windows Services

> By default, the tcruntime-instance.bat script creates all tc Runtime
>   instances under the `INSTALL_DIR\springsource-tc-server-edition`
>   directory, where `INSTALL_DIR` refers to the directory in which you
>   installed tc Server, such as `c:\home\tcserver` and edition is
>   `developer` or `standard`. Each particular tc Runtime instance lives
>   in its own directory; this directory translates into the server's
>   `CATALINA_BASE` variable. This is the default behavior of the command
>   script; you might have specified a different location of your tc
>   Runtime instance. If so, adjust the following procedure accordingly.
>
> In the following procedure, it is assumed that you installed a tc
>   Server Standard Edition.
>
> To start and stop tc Runtime instances as Windows Services:
>
> 1. If this is the first time that you will install and start the tc Runtime instance after creating it, start a command prompt window and
>      continue with this procedure.
>
>    If you have already installed the tc Runtime instance as a Windows Service, use the Windows Services control panel to start and stop it.
> 2. - Change to the CATALINA_BASE\bin directory of the tc Runtime instance you want to start or stop.
>    - For example, if you installed tc Server in `c:\home\tcserver` and created a new tc Runtime instance called myserver:
>
>      `prompt> cd c:\home\tcserver\springsource-tc-server-standard\myserver\bin`
>    - If you are using the Developer Edition of tc Server, the `CATALINA_BASE` directory will include the
>        springsource-tc-server-developer directory.
> 3. Install the tc Runtime instance as a Windows service:
>
>    `prompt> tcruntime-ctl.bat install`
>
>    The command installs the tc Runtime instance as an automatic Windows Service, which means that the tc Runtime instance starts
>      automatically when you start the Windows computer. You can change this
>      behavior using the Windows Service control panel.
>
>    You should see a message indicating a successful installation:
>
>    `wrapper | SpringSource tc Runtime - tcserver-c-home-tcserver-springsource-tc-server-standard-myserver
>      installed.`
> 4. Now, and subsequently, start and stop the tc Runtime instance by using the Windows Services console. The tc Runtime instance is
>      displayed in the console with the name SpringSource tc Runtime -
>      unique-name, where unique-name is a unique combination of server name
>      and server directory.
>
> To uninstall the tc Runtime service, execute the following command:
>
> ```
> prompt> tcruntime-ctl.bat uninstall
> ```
>
> Although SpringSource recommends that you always install the tc
>   Runtime instance as a Windows service and stop and start it using the
>   Services console, you can also stop and start the tc Runtime instance
>   manually. See tcruntime-ctl Command Reference for the full list of
>   commands of the `tcruntime-ctl` script.

Source [7.2 Starting and Stopping tc Runtime Instances](http://static.springsource.com/projects/tc-server/2.1/getting-started/html/ch07s02.html#postinstall-startstop-tcserver-windows)